# memoir: How can I omit the endnote header if there are no endnotes?

Tags: memoir, endnotes

I'm using the memoir style. I want endnotes printed at the end of each chapter. I also want a special header above each set of endnotes.

I have tried this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{memoir}
\renewcommand\pagenotesubhead[3]{}  % No section heading in endnotes
\setsecnumdepth{chapter}
\makepagenote
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\section{Technical Notes}}
 
\begin{document}
 
\chapter{The First}
 
Alpha beta gamma\pagenote{Note one} delta\pagenote{Note two}.
 
\printpagenotes*
 
\chapter{The Second}
 
Epsilon zeta eta theta.
 
\printpagenotes*
 
\end{document}
```

But that produces this output:

[image]

Even though chapter 2 has no endnotes, I still get the "Technical Notes" heading. How do I avoid that? I could, of course, remove the `\printpagenotes*` command after chapters with no notes, but that means that I have to be very careful about checking which chapters have notes and which don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something you "could" do

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\printmynotes{
  \immediate\closeout\@notefile
  \ifnum\pdffilesize{\jobname.ent}>0
  \printpagenotes*
  \else
  % reopen
  \immediate\openout\@notefile=\jobname.ent
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

then use

```
\printmynotes
```

in the text instead of `\printpagenotes*`

This uses that `\printpagenotes` closes the `.ent` file before printing the notes. So we close it early and use `\pdffilesize` to check the size. If non-zero we issue `\printpagenotes*` otherwise we reopen the note file.